# Acrobat Reader & saving last page I read?

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader, ebook

I like to read eBooks, but I tend to have a hard time keeping track on which page I am in which file. Is there a bookmark function or something similar that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Short question. Short answer. Great!

Comment: You can also read them in the Kindle app.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

In Adobe Reader:

> Edit → Preferences... (Ctrl+K)

In *Documents* category check the first option:

> Restore last view settings when reopening documents

Click **OK**

This works in 8, 9, 10, 11, and Acrobat Reader DC.

---

For Foxit Reader:

> File → Preferences...

In *History* category check the option:

> Restore last view settings when reopening

Click **OK**

Comment: This solution also works in 10x as well

Comment: Unfortunately, while it may perhaps work in the versions mentioned, it does nothing in version 11, so I moved from Adobe to Foxit where it works just fine.

Comment: @prl77, it worked just fine for me in 11.

Comment: +1 This works in Acrobat DC too. You might have to scroll down so that you can find the OK/Save button. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Sanoo well for me it's not working in DC. I re-installed it but still not working as expected.

Comment: @Anirban Nag 'tintinmj' Sorry, but I'm not using DC anymore. However, this worked for me until I stopped using it.

Comment: @AnirbanNag'tintinmj' it still works for me in Acrobat Reader DC. P.S. I have added an instruction for Foxit Reader too.

Comment: I normally view my PDFs in Adobe Acrobat Reader DC using the "scrolling mode". If I turn on "Restore last view settings when reopening documents" the page does not save the scroll state and opens with the first page on top.