# How to put a small bookmark in a PDF file?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Acrobat Reader & saving last page I read?](https://superuser.com/questions/149948/acrobat-reader-saving-last-page-i-read)

How could I put a navigation point in a PDF file, so that when I leave, then come back and open the file, I can go straight the point that I left earlier?

Answer (score 1):

[PDF-XChange Viewer](http://www.portablefreeware.com/index.php?id=1436) remembers your last page (and view) when you close and re-open a pdf.

Make sure this option is checked: `Edit → Preferences → Page Display → Initial Display`
This way you don't have to set a bookmark manually.

[image]